# I have earned a badge but it is not showing anywhere

Tags: bug, badges

I have earned the `socratic badged`, I formally received a message this morning about this, however, after I clicked `track next badge` I expected to see it showing on my profile, but it hasn't.

This is the only proof I got, when I try to add it for tracking it says that I already have it.

No, It doesn't change anything and I don't suffer out of lack of self esteem, (sometimes, out of ignorance it is quite the opposite) but the badges, reputation and specially the great answers and the great people I have come across here in this site do yes help me in my DBA studies as well as to be a better man.

[image]

To conclude:

[image]

if you think it is fair, please con-decorate me with my new gold badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's exciting to be the first person to earn [the Socratic badge](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/badges/134/socratic), but let's [wait the recommended 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716) before panicking too much. It's taken at least 100 days to earn, so 1 more day shouldn't hurt :)

Not saying you were wrong to raise this on meta, and I do understand you are rightly keen to have this gold badge display as it should.

...and now it does:

[image: Socratic awarded]